# Converting a string to datetime from "yyyy-MM-dd"

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime-format

Even though it seems like this question has been asked a bunch of times, I can't seem to find an answer that is specific to my question:

I have a variable that is read from an XML file by a C# XML parser.  It is a string, and is in the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.  I would like to read this variable into our database using `SQL`, but it needs to be in the proper datetime format in order for me to do this.  Unfortunately, I can't find any datetime formats for `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.  Am I missing something?

I would prefer to be able to convert the variable to datetime before I have to open my `SQL` connection, if possible.

Comment: Are you writing a SQL statement, using a stored procedure, using LINQ2SQL, NHibernate? It's also strange that you are complaining about the format as yyyy-MM-dd is close to or the exact format of SQL dates.

Comment: @EricH yyyy-MM-dd does not always work. Try `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH; SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-07-18');`

Comment: I have a string in format "yyyy-MM-dd", and I just want to be able to load that as an SQL datetime variable.  How do I do that?  The rest I can figure out I think now.

Comment: @SQLkiwi sure, but that only helps when there is actually a `CONVERT` in place. If you're just passing a string into a `DATETIME` parameter, it will either yield an error (for days > 12) or happily accept the wrong date (for days < 12).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> I would prefer to be able to convert the variable to datetime before I
>   have to open my SQL connection, if possible.

```
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-04-05", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: ParseExact would fail if the month or day was a single character which could happen. In that case though, the normal Parse works with YYYY-M-D format.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe ParseExact function can help you.

```
DateTime dResult = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-07-18", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure it will work you can use "TryParseExact". If it works "success" will be true. This way you are not risking a parse exception.

```
DateTime timestamp;
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact("2015-12-25", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using LINQ to XML, you can simply cast the element or attribute to `DateTime`:

```
DateTime date = (DateTime) element;
```

Then you can insert it into your database using parameterized SQL. I would argue *against* Aaron's suggestion: wherever possible, keep your data in its most natural form, which in vanilla .NET is a `DateTime`. The more time you can keep data in a meaningful representation, the better IMO.

If you're not using LINQ to XML, then the solutions from smink and Riera are fine - but I'd strongly encourage you to use LINQ to XML if you possibly can :)

Answer (score 1):

in sql server you can use the query
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120) AS [YYYY-MM-DD]

Answer (score 1):

```
stringDateFormat = "2015-12-25 00:00:00"

string dt= Convert.ToDateTime(stringDateFormat).ToString("d");    // output  -> 2015-12-25
```